# How to configure Query Store for resource usage

Tags: sql-server, query-store

I want to know how many milliseconds of CPU utilization happens for a particular database per 5-minute period.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the Query Store looks like a great way to find that out.  I wrote a query that pulls values from query_store_runtime_stats, and it seems to work fine.  Where I need help is understanding how to configure the Query Store appropriately, to make it store what I need, but no more than that.  I don't need execution plans, just CPU usage.  I might check every hour or so to gather the values, so I'd want to make sure that data stays around for at least a few hours.  Cleanup will have to happen automatically, and of course I can't allow it to switch to read-only mode if too much data gets stored.  What changes should I make to the following, for SQL Server 2019, to best meet my needs:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
    SET QUERY_STORE = ON
    (
        OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE,
        CLEANUP_POLICY = ( STALE_QUERY_THRESHOLD_DAYS = 90 ),
        DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 900,
        MAX_STORAGE_SIZE_MB = 1000,
        INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 60,
        SIZE_BASED_CLEANUP_MODE = AUTO,
        MAX_PLANS_PER_QUERY = 200,
        WAIT_STATS_CAPTURE_MODE = 1,
        QUERY_CAPTURE_MODE = CUSTOM,
        QUERY_CAPTURE_POLICY =
        (
            STALE_CAPTURE_POLICY_THRESHOLD = 24 HOURS,
            EXECUTION_COUNT = 30,
            TOTAL_COMPILE_CPU_TIME_MS = 1000,
            TOTAL_EXECUTION_CPU_TIME_MS = 100
        )
    );
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't currently configure Query Store to not collect query plans.

Comment: @ErikDarling: Thanks for that info.  That means that there will need to be enough storage reserved, especially since I'll be dealing almost exclusively with ad-hoc queries.  What settings can I use that would best meet my needs, namely letting query plans get discarded without losing the stats I need for the past few hours, no matter how many queries are executed during that period.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[sys.query_store_runtime_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-runtime-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) are directly tied to the [sys.query_store_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) via the `plan_id` column.

Not collecting the plan would also mean not collecting the runtime stats. You can limit the `MAX_PLANS_PER_QUERY = 1`, but you would be missing the data.

Query Store might not be the ideal tool for your use case. Consider a cross-DB query. If a query originates from one database but does majority of the work in a different one the CPU information is not where you would expect it.

To bucketize the CPU by database, I would probably use Extended Events along with some framework for easy consumption.

For example [WorkloadTools](https://github.com/spaghettidba/WorkloadTools) or [XESmartTarget](https://github.com/spaghettidba/XESmartTarget) - both by [Gianluca Sartori](https://spaghettidba.com/)